# how to clone a project on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku

I have a project on heroku working fine.  Now I want to create same project with different url (same code) as the one I have working now.  So that I can give the new url to the customer as a 'test' site.  I know in heroku i can just rename the url but I want to completely separate development from test (database wise).

What is the best solution? Do I start from scratch? cd into new folder on my machine...clone project from github...make new database -test ...push to heroku...etc. etc.

Answer (score 10):

Heroku toolbelt now provides a `fork` method to clone an existing application. It will duplicate your app with same source code, same database data and same add-ons.

Just type :

```
heroku fork --from sourceapp --to targetapp
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. For anyone seeing this answer in the future, however, this feature is being removed from the Heroku CLI on 12/1/17. In its place, Heroku recommends using Review Apps via their CI pipeline, instead of manually forking/creating individual, long-running applications. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps

Comment: The `fork` command has now been deprecated and so this option no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

You should check out [heroku_san](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san), I designed it specifically for deploying multiple environments to Heroku easily. It also has grown to include a lot of other niceties you'll need to automate when dealing with multiple "apps" like sharing and auto migrating with restarts.

Once you have it setup it's as simple as:

```
rake production deploy
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a method very similar to the one presented here: 
http://jqr.github.com/2009/04/25/deploying-multiple-environments-on-heroku.html

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best solution? Do I start from scratch? cd into new folder on my machine...clone project from github...make new database -test ...push to heroku...etc. etc.

Yeah, I'd just make a copy (clone) of the repo, either from GitHub (if you have it up on GitHub) or the current Heroku location. Then start a new project in Heroku and push the cloned (and possibly modified) second site up to Heroku as that project.