# How can i create a clone of an existing app on heroku from another heroku app as separate app?

Tags: heroku

I have a main app on heroku and another app A on git in location github:a.

I want to create, when it is necessary, copies of A as A1,A2,A3...AN as separate apps on heroku from my main app automatically with different parameters.

How can i do that?

Edit: This process should be done by my main app automatically.

Answer (score 18):

**Updating this answer due to Heroku command DEPRECATION**:

`heroku fork` has been deprecated as a core command as of 12/01/2017.

You will need to install the `heroku-fork` plugin to continue using this command.

`heroku plugins:install heroku-fork`

[Here is a link](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-fork) to the Github plugin repo.

Comment: I can't edit the answer, because there is my change is only one character. The command in this answer contains a trailing -j, which makes the command invalid if copied and used in full.

Comment: Nice catch. That was unintentional. I've updated the answer.

Comment: after installing, can execute via `heroku fork --from my-production-app --to my-development-app`

Answer (score 13):

Use `heroku fork` to copy an existing application, including add-ons, config vars, and Heroku Postgres data.

See this KB page: [Forking Applications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app).

Comment: Any idea of what to do now that heroku fork is sunsetting?

Comment: @Dan Review apps

Comment: review apps are not a solution when you need to duplicate a staging or production app.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku toolbelt now provides a fork method to clone an existing application, see my answer here :

[how to clone a project on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488810/how-to-clone-a-project-on-heroku/15897306#15897306)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature on Heroku called Review Apps. One can create copies of the app manually or set up automatic copies from new PRs on Github.
Read more at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps

Answer (score -3):

Simply create new applications and push your code to them.  If you need to copy data, checkout the [pgbackups transfers](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#transfers).

For management purposes, [check out this dev center article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments).

To do this programatically, you'll need to look at the Heroku gem, and then figure out a way of getting something to git push to the appropriate remote. I would be surprised if this was possible to be honest.

Comment: Ok but how can i create new apps and push my code automatically to them? It is a work should be done by my main app

Comment: Ah, you mean you want to do this programatically?  That's kind of an important thing to mention in the question.

Comment: Yes that exactly what i want. Sory for misleading my mistake.

Comment: Hi @OmerTemel, did you finally find a solution to do that ?